# Select splash screen image and background color based on the application theme not the system(ignore MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM.)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using DayNight theme for my android application, and I've made a values-night directory to customize my theme the way I want to, everything is working well, the problem is when I launch my application the splash screen color is chosen depending on the system theme.

let's say the system theme is light and my application is on the dark theme when launch my application the splash screen will be light them colors then the rest of the application will be in the dark theme, and if we change the application theme to light and the system theme to dark then when I launch my application the splash screen will be in the dark theme colors but the rest of the app will be in light theme.

I looked around and I found out that dayNight theme gets the default value for the application theme from the system theme, as you can read in the setDefaultNightMode descriptions

> Sets the default night mode. This is used across all activities/dialogs but can be overridden locally via setLocalNightMode(int).
>   This method only takes effect for those situations where applyDayNight() works. Defaults to MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM.
>   This only takes effect for components which are created after the call. Any components which are already open will not be updated.

I was wondering if there is a way to change that default value? or change the source of the default value.